# Open Port 22 on remote server using paramiko with python

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

The following is my code:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('server_name', username = 'anonymous', password = 'anything')
```

When I try this with specific servers, I get the `operation timed out` error. Trying to see if the problem was with the port, I used `telnet` to connect to the server but it didn't work (same error). That's why I believe that the problem lies in the port. Is there a way to open port 22 in a python script (with paramiko) or another solution to this problem?

Comment: If the server isn't running, you won't be able to start it with the client--well, unless there is some other server running that you can use.

Comment: What makes you believe that you should be able to SSH to the server even if the server does not have port 22 open?

Comment: Write the your script output